# Getting wrong output for infix/postfix in java using stacks

Tags: java, stack, stringtokenizer, postfix-notation, infix-notation

For input (1+3)*(1+3) I'm getting 1 3 + * 1 3 + for output, when it should be 1 3 + 1 3 + *. I have debugged and cannot figure out why multiplication does not hold until the end. Am I not comparing it the right way in checkOp()?

```
public String infixToPostfix() throws StackEmptyException{

    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    String expression = jtfInfix.getText();
    String delims = "+-*/()123456789 ";
    StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(expression, delims, true);
    String result = "";

    while(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){

        String token = strToken.nextToken();

        if(token.equals("(")){
            s.push(token);
        }   
        else if(token.equals(")")){

            while(s.peek().equals("(") != true){
                result += " " + s.pop();
            }
        }//first elseif
        else if (checkOp(token)){
            if(s.isEmpty() == true) {
                s.push(token);
            }
            else {
                if(getOrder(token) < findOrder(s.peek())) {
                    result += " " + s.pop();
                    s.push(token);
                }
                else {
                    s.push(token);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            result += " " + token;
        }
    }
    while(s.isEmpty()) {
        result += s.pop();
    }

    return result;
}// infixToPostFix()

public int findOrder(String token) {
    int order = 0;
    if((token.equals("+")) || (token.equals("-"))) {
        order = 1;
    }
    else if((token.equals("*")) || (token.equals("%"))) {
        order = 2;
    }
    else if(token.equals(")")) {
        order = 0;
    }
    return order;
}

public int getOrder(String token) {
    int order = 0;
    if((token.equals("+")) || (token.equals("-")) ) {
        order = 1;
    }
    else if((token.equals("*"))  || (token.equals("%")) ) {
        order = 2;
    }
    return order;
}


private boolean checkOp(String token) {
    return ((token.equals("+"))  ||  (token.equals("-"))  || (token.equals("*"))  || 
            (token.equals("%"))  );            

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors

First you need to pop the parenthesis once it has been matched

```
while(s.peek().equals("(") != true){
    result += " " + s.pop();
}
s.pop(); // pop the matching left parenthesis
```

and you want to pop everything off the stack once you have finished

```
while(s.isEmpty()) {
    result += s.pop();
}
```

should be

```
while(!s.isEmpty()) {
    result += " " + s.pop();
}
```

as a comment logging is helpful to see what is happebing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but output remains the same.

Comment: @H22 BevynQ's answer is correct.  The code shown results in " 1 3 + 1 3 +" with a non empty stack of [(, *, (].  Your claim that it outputs " 1 3 + * 1 3 +" does not seem correct.  Did you maybe change your code after you posted the question?

Comment: @H22 I was unable to replicate your output. My output matched @Tibrogargan. I replaced `jtfInfix.getText()` with `"(1+3)*(1+3)"` for my test

Comment: I'm sure, for some reason when i debug it just wont recognize "*" or " "%" as an operator.

Comment: `%` is not in your delims variable. I would suggest you add logging messages to see what is going on.